# How to concatenate rows in Sharepoint 2013 custom list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have various custom lists that are sending their final total score/data to one master list used as a leaderboard (via a SP2010 workflow).

I have the leaderboard set up with the following columns:
Created by
Week 1 total
Week 2 total
Week 3 total

However, When each list sends the "score" to the leaderboard it creates a new row for the user. So, using the above columns as reference I would get the created by  then the wk1 total, then the second row would be same created by and the wk2 total and a third column with the created by and the wk 3 total. Is there a way to merge all the rows so that I have one row for each user(created by) with each week total filled out with its own unique data? Or, is there a way to use SPD to create a workflow that brings in the data into the correct column/cell for the user/row instead of creating a new row each time it brings the data over as it currently does?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that springs to mind is to re-structure your list so that you have columns for weeks 1 through 5 in each line and then subtotal those.  Without seeing the list firsthand - it feels you have one column for weekly total and you're list is having trouble breaking it out by week submitted. Having all weeks in the list so it comes in clean and your list not having to work to recognize which week it is, as each would have their own column, may make calculated fields simple. Then making a leader board becomes easier.  Then you can build views to filter or group by user(created by) field and make calculated subtotals in those views. Then it's a matter of training your users to switch list views, or you making a new view the default view for your list.